# Has programming with C gotten easier with operating system security and execute disable?

Tags: c, security, crash, environment

I understand that in the past with C you could screw up pointers and memory allocation, and potentially accidentally corrupt other running programs or the operating system itself outside of your program, and crash the system. This would require a restart to pick up the pieces and continue with program development.

Have system security improvements stopped this from happening?

In the past with MSDOS and Windows 3.1/95/98/Me, and MacOS prior to version 10, (generally before preemptive multitasking became the norm for everything) system security generally did not exist. Programs had full control to write data anywhere at any time.

But now with more modern system design and process security, programs generally are blocked by system security from accidentally or intentionally damaging anything else.

The execute-disable feature of modern processors may also be helping with preventing accidentally jumping to a random memory location and running whatever is there as processor machine code.

So how badly can you screw up with modern programming with C without attempting to hack the operating system security?

Can you still manage to accidentally crash the whole system? I assume this is no longer possible. The kernel or other system security steps in and halts the action.

Can you corrupt your login environment and have to log out and back in again? I assume this too is prevented, as processes should not normally have access to other process memory space, even within your own login security environment.

In general it seems like programming in C may now be much easier than it was in the past just due to these system protections that are now used everywhere, to keep you from shooting yourself and the system in the foot.

Comment: Well, ordinary user programs are protected by the system - but if you write e. g. device drivers, you are quickly back at what was before - just imagine dereferencing a null pointer in a interrupt service routine...

Answer (score 4):

In the realm of what you can accidentally do, it has certainly gotten easier than the MS-DOS days. I remember a bug that corrupted the in-memory disk cache. I was lucky to have anything left after that one.

Now, unless you're writing C code that runs inside the kernel, that's not possible to do anymore. Nor is crashing the OS in general unless you are actively trying to exploit a flaw.

The various other things, like the NX bit and other such attempts to erect a bit of a security fence around C programs, they do make your program crash faster and at a place closer to where the error really happened. But they aren't anywhere near the level of win that you got with simple separated address spaces. They are designed to make active attempts to exploit things much more difficult, and they're far better at this than they are at catching accidents or mistakes.

And corrupting the login environment as distinct from the OS as a whole is also generally not statistically likely. Though if your program is doing sophisticated file manipulation you could have a bug that messed up the user's files.

And, short of actually crashing the OS you can accidentally cause resource exhaustion. And while this can often be recovered from, it's very uncomfortable while it's going on. Your system slows to a crawl and may not even be able to launch processes. Linux has some protection against this. And if you put your development environment in a cgroup, you can prevent it completely.

Of course, anything that an active exploit could do, you could do by mistake. But, I'm talking about the statistical likelihood of doing these things by accident.

Probably the biggest improvement since separated address spaces are tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) that monitor your program on-the-fly for out-of-bounds acesses or accesses to freed memory and the like.

MS-DOS and early Windows were rather weird for their use as general purpose computers with high-quality C development environments and also having such promiscuous memory. It's taken Windows a long time to outgrow that, and programming practices on the platform are still a little weird.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes.

On computers that use virtual memory and keep data and code separate, it is much harder to write catastrophic  bugs as you'll get a hardware exception (that the OS translates into something softer). So you can't have bugs that run off to overwrite your own executable code, or have runaway code that starts executing random "op codes" from the data segment. The bug will still be there of course, and needs to be fixed. But it will be a whole lot less mysterious and not nearly as disastrous.

Computers that don't have these security features require more care and testing by the programmer.

Crashing the whole system is still quite possible, but mostly this is because of bugs in the OS and API. The occasional "blue screen of death" in Windows is still a thing. With some effort you could also lag down the whole computer by using 100% CPU or by allocating excessive amounts of heap memory, turning it next to useless.